# How do i return compatibility level of just one database?

Tags: powershell, azure-sql-database, ssas

I referenced this page: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/hh213141(v=sql.100)

```
Import-Module SqlServer

$as = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server  
$as.connect("$Server")  

$as.databases

Write-Host "Compatibility level ="$as.DefaultCompatibilityLevel
```

but this returns ALL databases back...

I want to specify just one database to get the compatibility level of...

I tried this,

```
$as.databases["$Database"]
```

the DB i am interested in has lvl 1103, 
but it seems not to return the proper level, because its returning 1200...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with this API, but I see that the [`$as.Databases` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices.server.databases) is of type [`DatabaseCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices.databasecollection).  The `DatabaseCollection` class does have [indexers](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices.databasecollection.item) that take either an `Int32` or a `String`, like you're attempting to use with `$as.databases["$Database"]`.

Note that the documentation for the `String` indexer says the parameter is an "identifier" for the database to be returned.  Also note that the [`Database` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices.database) has separate properties for [`ID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices.namedcomponent.id) and [`Name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices.namedcomponent.name), so there is a distinction between the two.  So, my suggestion is, make sure you are passing the ID, not the name, when you try to retrieve a `Database` instance that way.

Alternatively, if you do want to search by name you could use the [`FindByName` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices.databasecollection.findbyname)...

```
$as.Databases.FindByName($Database)
```

...or [`GetByName` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices.databasecollection.getbyname)...

```
$as.Databases.GetByName($Database)
```

...with the difference being that the former returns `$null` if no such database exists and the latter throws an exception.

If all else fails you could retrieve the desired database like this...

```
$as.Databases | Where-Object { $_.ID -eq $Database }
```

...or like this...

```
$as.Databases | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $Database }
```

...depending on which property corresponds to the value in `$Database`.

Finally, in your code you are attempting to access a `DefaultCompatibilityLevel` property, which I don't see defined in the [`Database` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices.database).  There is, however, a [`CompatibilityLevel` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices.core.database.compatibilitylevel).

Comment: i was just about to post that i found FindByName($Database) method lol. but that just returns the DB name, i need to return its compatibility. when i do this: $c = $as.GetByName($Database) Write-Host "Compatibility level =" $c.DefaultCompatibilityLevel   ...... it writes nothing

Comment: It might only be outputting the `Name` property by default.  Try `$c | Get-Member` to see what properties are available or `$c | Format-List -Property *` to display all property values.  Also, I don't see a `DefaultCompatibilityLevel` property on the `Database` class, but there is a [`CompatibilityLevel` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices.core.database.compatibilitylevel).

Comment: YES! thats it! $c.CompatibilityLevel :D. you sir just saved me a lot of time! not sure if you wanna edit your answer to include the full resolution we discussed in comments, but im gonna mark it as correct :)